# ExtJS does not identify IE11

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4, internet-explorer-11

I have a lot of problems when **ExtJS** (v4.0.7) does not identify **IE11**.

In this case occurs many UI bugs under IE11 browser.

I couldn't use "**flax: 1**" for grid columns and other **layout** stuff.

Comment: IE11 was released well after Ext 4.0.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution which brilliantly fixed all my problems under IE11.

So, I have the HTML where I include next files:

- < script src="lib/ext-4.0.7/ext-all.js">..........................# ExtJS lib
- < script src="app/util/overrides/**lib-overrides.js**">.....# ExtJS overrides
- < script src="app/main.js">.........................................# Application

In **lib-overrides.js** I insert the code which fix IE11:

```
Ext.apply(Ext, ((a = navigator.userAgent) && /Trident/.test(a) && /rv:11/.test(a)) ? {isIE:true, isIE11:true, ieVersion: 11} : {});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me.